# some thing wrong with memory?

Tags: objective-c

I am developing a game using Cocos2D. I got some error out of sudden after few time successfully played the game. And When i debugged it gives the error called EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

here is the code.

```
    -(void) winGame
        {
//the debug stopped here...
            WinningScene *winner = [WinningScene node];
            [[Director sharedDirector] replaceScene:[FadeTransition transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:winner]];
        }
    if ((touchCount > 0 && touchCount ==2) && (rangeY2 > 0.0 && rangeY2 < 20.0))
        {
            bras++;
            if (bras == 1)
            {
                //[self winGame];
                [self runAction:[Sequence 
                                 actionOne:[DelayTime actionWithDuration:0.5]
                                 two: [CallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(winGame)]]];

            }
```

Could u guys tell me why ?

Comment: The memory problem is not in the code you pasted. Given your comment, I'm assuming the method call [WinningScene node] was the problem, but it's rather hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's a bit difficult to debug `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.  They usually indicate either accessing array out-of-bound, or dereferencing a released object.  Go over you code, and check that you retain any reference you assign to field and that you set such fields to `nil` whenever you release them.